# How to configure an Azure DevOps release to complete all its stages before starting a new one

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am setting up an Azure DevOps release pipeline with three different stages. As shown in the following screenshot a new release has already started even though the preceding release is still running.

[image: Main Release]

Is there a way to configure a release to complete all its stages before the next in the queue is getting started?

Comment: Does Release-152 and Release-153 assign to the same agent? If the have different Agents the would try to build parallel, if it's the same it should be serial.

Comment: All three different stages assign to the same agent pool. The agent pool consists of two self-hosted agents.

Comment: you could try to deactivate one agent and checkout the behavior of the release pipeline.

Comment: Why you want the later release executed after all of stages of previous release completed? For example, the stage2's running will not have any affect on the stage1 of later release pipeline.

Comment: Because stage 1 was meant to do preparations for stage 2 and 3. So the execution of stage 1 of a newer release affects stage 2 and 3 of the previous release. I assume I misunderstood the intentions of stages in a release pipeline in general.

Comment: @millo, No, the execution of stage 1 does not has any affection to stage2 and stage3. In release, the stages are **independent** of each other. Only the stage 1 execution of next release has the in fact relevant with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more readable, I will talk based on the pic you shared in the question.

In fact, in the release which has multiple stages, the stages are independent of each other. As you can see about the task job defined for different stages, we can know that the execution for different stages are running independently.

The only connection between each stages is **the order of execution** which determined by **After release** and **After stage**.

[image]

And also, as the pic mention below:

[image]

As you can see that once the **Stage1** of **Releae-152** execution finished, the **Stage1** of **Realse-153** will be executed follow by. As I mentioned in previous comment, only the same execution **deployed to the same stage** can affect each other. For stage1, the Release-153 can **override** the stage1 in Release-152.

Since there has several release pipeline in queued, as the default, the server will executed the deployment which in same stage firstly. That's why you see the Stage1 of **Releae-153** running firstly than Stage2 of **Releae-152**.