# Azure devops Rest API invoke release

Tags: azure-devops, devops, release, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

Currently i'm using Azure DevOps Rest API call from the CI to invoke the releases from a release definition. During the process i'm invoking releases one after another. All releases starts at the same time. Currently i have added a manual intervention at the start of every releases. SO when first release got finish i will go and resume the second releases and on completing that resume the third releases. But i want to remove this manual intervention and releases should start only after finishing the previous releases. For example if i'm triggering three releases

```
Release1,
Release2,
Release3
```

While Release1 is running both Release2 and Release3 should wait. On completing Release1, the Release2 should start without manual intervention and Release3 should still wait. On completing Release2,  start Release3 without manual intervention.

Comment: Just checking to see if the information provided was helpful.

Comment: No, I tried a different approach.

I used Rest API to call Release2 after Release1 and called Releases3 after Release2

Comment: Hi Patrick,  i did

Comment: I would recommend the approach you took, have 1 call 2 and 2 call 3 at the end of each release. If you are familiar with PowerShell check out the AzurePipelinesPS module to make those api calls with PowerShell. https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzurePipelinesPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I specified, I used Azure Devops Rest API to invoke multiple dependency releases. But I was calling all the releases one after another from the CI process itself. So I put the Manual intervention for the following releases. But now I updated my process to call the dependency release just after finishing the parent release. So I again took advantage of the REST API feature for the same. Also, the variable collection is same for all the releases. So I'm setting the release variable through REST API and use the same variable for setting the variable for successive release. So Release2 is called after calling Release1 and Release3 is called after calling Release2 using REST API.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26935903)

Comment: What you mean?. This is the answer i was requested to put by Patrick.

Answer (score 1):

> While Release1 is running both Release2 and Release3 should wait. On
> completing Release1, the Release2 should start without manual
> intervention and Release3 should still wait. On completing Release2,
> start Release3 without manual intervention.

This will only occur when you are trying to create 3 releases in the same agent. If there have different agents, there should be running in parallel.

Since you are using a single release pipeline. Not sure why you want the later release executed after all of stages of previous release completed.

In release, the stages are independent of each other.

You could also take a look at this similar question. [How to configure an Azure DevOps release to complete all its stages before starting a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57405813/how-to-configure-an-azure-devops-release-to-complete-all-its-stages-before-start)