# Azure worker - Complete the release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, worker

I have a release pipeline composed of several stages

[image: release pipeline]

The tfs server have only one worker.
When i start a release, the worker run stages randomly.

The problem is : if someone else start another pipeline, sometimes the worker take the other pipeline before getting back to the next stage.

Is there a way to lock the worker on the entire release pipeline ?

Comment: Similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57405813/how-to-configure-an-azure-devops-release-to-complete-all-its-stages-before-start?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running a pipeline, a job is the unit of scale. This means each job can potentially run on a different agent.

> Each job runs on an agent. A job represents an execution boundary of a set of steps. All of the steps run together on the same agent.

Next to that,

> A stage is a logical boundary in the pipeline. It can be used to mark separation of concerns (for example, Build, QA, and production).

More information: [Azure Pipelines - Key concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/key-pipelines-concepts).

You should also have a look at the [Pipeline run sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runs?view=azure-devops). It clearly explains how the entire pipeline-process works.

> Whenever Azure Pipelines needs to run a *job*, it will ask the pool for an agent.

If the availability of the agent is the issue, you might want to add more agents to the pool. If needed, you can even run multiple agents on the same machine.

> Although multiple agents can be installed per machine, we strongly suggest to only install one agent per machine. Installing two or more agents may adversely affect performance and the result of your pipelines.

Comment: If i understand well, the differents stage are not seen as a logical pipeline by the agents ?

Comment: Each job is a new logical unit. There is 0 guarantee the next job will land in the same agent or to boost a job to a higher position in the queue based on the fact that it's a 2nd or 3rd job in the same pipeline.

Comment: So maybe there is a solution to give a specific job a overall high priority ?